# Entity framework relationships

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a problem with relationships in Entity-framework

Here is my problem :

I have two classes : User and Group

- A group must have ONE Owner (User)
- A group can have 0 or severals Members (User)
- An User can be the owner of 0 or severals group

User.cs :

```
    public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int userId { get; set; }


    [Display(Name="Firstname")]
    public string firstname { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Lastname")]
    public string lastname { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string email { get; set; }

}
```

Group.cs :

```
    public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int idGroup { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public User owner { get; set; }
    public List<User> members { get; set; }

    public Group()
    {
        members = new List<User>();
    }

}
```

And here is the insert group function :

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Group group)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            group.owner = db.Users.Attach((User)Session["user"]);
//Current user stored in session and already presents in User table
            db.Groups.Add(group);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        return View(group);
    }
```

The problem is :

- When I run debugging into the insert function, the "owner" attribute is correctly set (at db.savechanges)
- But after, when I select a group in db (Group group =
  db.Groups.Find(id);), the "owner" parameter is null.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using EF Code First? Or are you using the EF designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class Group
{
    [Key]
    public int idGroup { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; } 
    public virtual User owner { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> members { get; set; }

    public Group()
    {
        members = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem
 `Group group = db.Groups.Find(id).Include("owner");`

Comment: This code does not work. (Error : method include does not exist for object group) Tried to do Group group = db.Groups.Include("owner").Find(id); but does not work too